# Check null for all participants in a union LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

As an example for the following scenario, how can I check whether `quizType1Attempt` and/or `quizType2Attempt` is null (without checking before these statements)?

```
var resultRecord = studentDomain.quizType1Attempts.Select(quizType1Attempt => new resultRecord {
    Id = quizType1Attempt.Id,
    Subject = quizType1Attempt.Subject,
    ...
}).Union(studentDomain.quizType2Attempts.Select(quizType2Attempt => new resultRecord {
    Id = quizType2Attempt.Id,
    Subject = quizType2Attempt.Subject
    ...
})).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `Where()` predicate to filter your items in the list.

```
var resultRecord = studentDomain.quizType1Attempts.Where(q1 => q1 != null).Select(quizType1Attempt => new resultRecord {
    Id = quizType1Attempt.Id,
    Subject = quizType1Attempt.Subject,
    ...
}).Union(studentDomain.quizType2Attempts.Where(q2 => q2 != null).Select(quizType2Attempt => new resultRecord {
    Id = quizType2Attempt.Id,
    Subject = quizType2Attempt.Subject
    ...
})).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried it but did not work.

Comment: What didn't work? Do you have an error?

Comment: @klekmek, apply the _Where_ clause to each quizType1Attempts **and** quizType2Attempts. Obviously, if you forget to filter quizType2Attempts for _null_ values, you'll get an exception when the predicate in the _Select_ clause for quizType2Attempts tries to derefence either _quizType2Attempt.Id_ or _quizType2Attempt.Subject_ when the current _quizType2Attempt_ happens to be _null_...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace My answer was not comprehensive enough. Obviously the where predicate has to be applied to both lists. I will update.

Comment: Normally my code is working fine, but in the unit test, it is throwing "System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no elements" exception. 
I know quiz types can be null. Normally, it is initialize as an empty array. This problem occurs in the unit test. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Just add null-coalescing operator (?) after nullable object.

```
var resultRecord = studentDomain.quizType1Attempts?.Select(quizType1Attempt => new resultRecord
        {
            Id = quizType1Attempt.Id,
            Subject = quizType1Attempt.Subject
        }) ?? new List<resultRecord>().Union(studentDomain.quizType2Attempts?.Select(quizType2Attempt => new resultRecord
        {
            Id = quizType2Attempt.Id,
            Subject = quizType2Attempt.Subject
        }) ?? new List<resultRecord>()).ToList();
```

Comment: Normally my code is working fine, but in the unit test, it is throwing "System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no elements" exception. I know quiz types can be null. Normally, it is initialized as an empty array. This problem occurs in the unit test. Can you say why is that? Thank you for your response.